# More detailed version of "file"

Tags: linux, command-line, files, file-command

A year ago I've used a more advanced version of `file`, I think this was on a Debian based linux and it was in their main repository.

Compared to `file`, it would show some more information such as if the file is a symlink and if its a script some information about the script itself.

I don't think I can rest without finding out the name of that tool.

Comment: Ian F. Darwin's `file` utility shows all of this information by
default.

Comment: Yes, I don't know what `file` you have that doesn't do this. Can you add the output of your `file` to your question? What do you get if you run `file link` where "link" is a symbolic link? What operating system are you using?

Comment: you may have been using an alias

Comment: 100% it wasn't an alias to file, because we used file as well alongside this other command. The command is somewhat relatable to file but its output was more detailed and showed extra information that file does not do. - It really was a command you would find and be "Why didn't I know about this earlier".

Comment: you mean like `file /bin/fgrep` `/bin/fgrep: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
`  or more detail than that?

Comment: https://www.darwinsys.com/file/ links to Darwin's `file` executable